# value based thread lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Forgive me if this has been asked before. I have looked around a lot, but I get the feeling that I don't have the proper vocabulary to find this by searching the web.

I have a multithreaded application in python. I want to be able to lock a certain block of code but only to other threads with a certain condition. Let me give an example: There are three threads, `thread_a`, `thread_b` and `thread_c`. Each thread may run through the function `foo` at any time. I don't want any two threads with `bar` equal to each other to be able to access `Code block ALPHA` at the same time. However, I don't want to block threads whose `bar` value is different. In this case, let's say `thread_a` has a `bar == "cat"` and hits  line `(3)` first. Before `thread_a` hits line `(5)`, let's say `thread_b`, with `bar == "cat"` hits line `(3)`. I would like for `thread_b` to wait. But if `thread_c` comes along, with `bar == "dog"`, I would like for it to be able to keep going.

```
(1) def foo(bar):
(2)    
(3)     lock(bar)
(4)     # Code block ALPHA (two threads with equivalent bar should not be in here)
(5)     unlock(bar)
```

As another note, the possible values for `bar` are completely unpredictable but with a very high chance of collision.

Thank you for any help. The library I am looking at is the [python threading library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#with-locks)

Comment: Is `bar` finite? If it is then you can set up as many mutexes you want and then lock the mutex that corresponds to whatever `bar` value your thread has.

Comment: @numeral, good question. Bar is not finite in the sense that you could reasonably allocate a mutex for every possible case. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: In that case the only thing I can think of is that you're going to have to keep track of what `bar` you've come across and lock dynamically. Anything I think of has some sort of shared memory model involved. Which means you're going to have to have a master lock that will lock all your dynamic locks. In other words you'd just have one mutex that would lock all threads. Sorry couldn't help. :/

Comment: If you try to use a two-tier locking system, make sure you don't end up with one thread holding the master lock and trying to lock a value lock while another thread holds that value lock and tries to hold the master lock. Deadlock isn't fun.

Comment: @user2357112, might you know of any good example implementations for a two-tier locking system. I would hate to hit deadlock.

Comment: @PhillipMartin: I don't.

Comment: Are you expecting to see a lot of different `bar` values, enough that we couldn't keep a separate condition variable for every recorded `bar` value for the life of the program?

Comment: A rough estimate would be anywhere from ~10K to ~1M `bar` values during the life of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Good news: I was able to reproduce the `release_lock` problem you encountered using my original answer via a somewhat crude testbed I cobbled together, and fix the issue using a counting mechanism (as you suggested) — at least a far as I can tell with my testing apparatus.

Now two separate shared dictionaries are used, one to keep track of the "names" or values associated with each lock as before, and another to keep track of how many threads are using each one at a given time.

As before, lock names must be hashable values so they can be used as keys in dictionaries.

```
import threading

namespace_lock = threading.Lock()
namespace = {}
counters = {}

def aquire_lock(value):
    with namespace_lock:
        if value in namespace:
            counters[value] += 1
        else:
            namespace[value] = threading.Lock()
            counters[value] = 1

    namespace[value].acquire()

def release_lock(value):
    with namespace_lock:
        if counters[value] == 1:
            del counters[value]
            lock = namespace.pop(value)
        else:
            counters[value] -= 1
            lock = namespace[value]

    lock.release()

# sample usage    
def foo(bar):
    aquire_lock(bar)
    # Code block ALPHA (two threads with equivalent bar should not be in here)
    release_lock(bar)
```

Comment: Thank you for putting effort into writing this. I'm going to test it out and report back. It looks promising.

Comment: I'm impressed this got so far prior to any testing. Only problem I've found is that values can be popped from `namespace` prematurely. When two threads try to acquire the same value, when `release_lock` is called by the first thread, it pops the value, and the second thread falls through `namespace[value].acquire()`.  When the second thread calls `release_lock`, the value is no longer in `namespace` and can't be popped. I think all it would take to fix is adding a counting mechanism to let the releasing thread know if it should pop. Awesome answer overall!

Answer (score 3):

Have one lock, acquired whenever a thread tries to enter or exit the critical section, and use separate condition variables for each value of `bar`. The following could probably be optimized to create less condition variables, but doing so for this post felt like premature optimization:

```
import collections
import contextlib
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

wait_tracker = collections.defaultdict(lambda: (False, 0, threading.Condition(lock)))

@contextlib.contextmanager
def critical(bar):
    with lock:
        busy, waiters, condition = wait_tracker[bar]
        if busy:
            # Someone with the same bar value is in the critical section.

            # Record that we're waiting.
            waiters += 1
            wait_tracker[bar] = busy, waiters, condition

            # Wait for our turn.
            while wait_tracker[bar][0]:
                condition.wait()

            # Record that we're not waiting any more.
            busy, waiters, condition = wait_tracker[bar]
            waiters -= 1

        # Record that we're entering the critical section.
        busy = True
        wait_tracker[bar] = busy, waiters, condition
    try:
        # Critical section runs here.
        yield
    finally:
        with lock:
            # Record that we're out of the critical section.
            busy, waiters, condition = wait_tracker[bar]
            busy = False
            if waiters:
                # Someone was waiting for us. Tell them it's their turn now.
                wait_tracker[bar] = busy, waiters, condition
                condition.notify()
            else:
                # No one was waiting for us. Clean up a bit so the wait_tracker
                # doesn't grow forever.
                del wait_tracker[bar]
```

Then each thread that wants to enter the critical section does the following:

```
with critical(bar):
    # Critical section.
```

This code is untested, and parallelism is hard, especially locks-and-shared-memory parallelism. I make no guarantees that it will work.

Comment: When I get the chance, I will take a close look at this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class oriented solution, suitable if you need several separate groups of locks.

```
# A dynamic group of locks, useful for parameter based locking.
class LockGroup(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock_dict = {}
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    # Returns a lock object, unique for each unique value of param.
    # The first call with a given value of param creates a new lock, subsequent
    # calls return the same lock.
    def get_lock(self, param):
        with self.lock:
            if param not in self.lock_dict:
                self.lock_dict[param] = threading.Lock()
            return self.lock_dict[param]
```