# Redis: Threading Locks On Multiple Nodes [Python]

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, networking, redis

When working with Python3, `Redis` (actually `Flask` and `Flask-Redis`), I often find myself in a situation where I load data from a Redis DB with

```
data = redis_client.hgetall(id)
```

change some values and then store the data again with

```
redis_client.hset(id, data)
```

This is obviously not thread-safe, so I added threading locks, using the implementation I found here:

[value based thread lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624289/value-based-thread-lock)

```
import threading

namespace_lock = threading.Lock()
namespace = {}
counters = {}

def aquire_lock(value):
    with namespace_lock:
        if value in namespace:
            counters[value] += 1
        else:
            namespace[value] = threading.Lock()
            counters[value] = 1

    namespace[value].acquire()

def release_lock(value):
    with namespace_lock:
        if counters[value] == 1:
            del counters[value]
            lock = namespace.pop(value)
        else:
            counters[value] -= 1
            lock = namespace[value]

    lock.release()

# sample usage    
def foo(id):
    aquire_lock(id)
    data = redis_client.hgetall(id)
    # ...
    redis_client.hset(id, data)
    release_lock(id)
```

This works just fine when running multiple threads on a single node, but when running multiple nodes behind a node balancer, information about locks is not shared among them.

**What would be the usual strategy to lock access to `Redis` ressources, when having multiple nodes access the same database?**

So far I've tried `Redlock` (actually `Flask-Redlock`), what led to code like:

```
from flask_redlock import RedisLock

redis_lock = RedisLock()
redis_lock.init_app(app)

with redis_lock.lock(f'{id}.lock', 3000, retry=10, interval=0.2) as lock:
    if not lock:
        return 'busy!'

    # Code Execution Part
    time.sleep(10)
```

but this allows me to execute the code with a second thread before the `sleep` method of the first thread finishes. I therefore concluded that it might only protect functionality in direct relation with `Redis`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have used the Flask-Redlock incorrectly. 3000 is TTL that means lock would automatically expire after 3 seconds and your sleep time is 10 seconds.

If you test your code than you would find that other thread can not acquire the lock within 3 seconds. If your execution takes N seconds than always lock for N+delta (delta  > 0) seconds. IMO you should add atleast 2 second as delta, 2 second is round trip time for lock/unlock combined, even you can take more given you would unlock the lock once you're done with usage.